# How to return data between two dates using Stored Procuedure from multiple data inputs

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

We currently have a table that has a new record created each time a field is tapped (representing a RAG status).  Currently if tapped Once the stored value would reflect e.g. Red; if they were then to tap again it would change the visual to Green but a new record would be written to the table.

e.g.

```
Field1                 Red                     Time/Date
Field1                 Green                 Time/Date
```

We need to consider how best to report, recognising multiple rows could be possible for the same field (no limit on how many times people could cycle through), on what the "active" value is.  Currently this is only discernible by identifying the newest record (by Time/Date) but if running over several days this would make a report quite complex given how many records could exist for each day….

We have created a statement (below) however want the data to be shown in one  column rather than one row:

```
 select(select Value_Colour from  SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data where Metric_Year = 2018 and Metric_Month = 3 and Metric_Day = 22 and Board_Metrics_ID = 1 order by Date_Created desc limit 1),
       (select Value_Colour from  SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data where Metric_Year = 2018 and Metric_Month = 3 and Metric_Day = 23 and Board_Metrics_ID = 1 order by Date_Created desc limit 1),
       (select Value_Colour from  SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data where Metric_Year = 2018 and Metric_Month = 3 and Metric_Day = 24 and Board_Metrics_ID = 1 order by Date_Created desc limit 1),
       (select Value_Colour from  SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data where Metric_Year = 2018 and Metric_Month = 3 and Metric_Day = 25 and Board_Metrics_ID = 1 order by Date_Created desc limit 1),
       (select Value_Colour from  SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data where Metric_Year = 2018 and Metric_Month = 3 and Metric_Day = 26 and Board_Metrics_ID = 1 order by Date_Created desc limit 1);
```

We also need this to be a stored procedure between two dates so we can change the dates easily (eg. 23/3/2018 - 29/3/2018).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the last record per day for a given metric.  You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select bmd.*
from SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data bmd
where bmd.Metric_Year = 2018 and Metric_Month = 3 and
      bmd.Metric_Day in (26, 27, 28) and bmd.Board_Metrics_ID = 1 and
      bmd.Date_Created = (select max(bmd2.Date_Created)
                          from SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data bmd2
                          where bmd2.Board_Metrics_ID = bmd.Board_Metrics_ID and
                                bmd2.Metric_Year = bmd.Metric_Year and
                                bmd2.Metric_Month = bmd.Metric_Month and
                                bmd2.Metric_Day = bmd.Metric_Day
                         );
```

This subquery can take advantage of an index on `Board_Metrics_Data(Metric_Year, Metric_Month, Metric_Day, Metrics_ID, Date_Created)`.

EDIT:

For an arbitrary range of dates:

```
select bmd.*
from SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data bmd
where bmd.Date_Created >= @start_date and bmd.Date_Created < @end_date and
      bmd.Board_Metrics_ID = 1 and
      bmd.Date_Created = (select max(bmd2.Date_Created)
                          from SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data bmd2
                          where bmd2.Board_Metrics_ID = bmd.Board_Metrics_ID and
                                date(bmd2.Date_Created) = date(bmd.Date_Created)
                         );
```

This version of the query is a bit harder to optimize.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is pretty much what we are looking for! However, we need to be able to put this into a stored procedure with 3 inputs (startDate, endDate and BMID) however the startDate and endDate could have different months and years, how could we do this?